# Cannot apply inherited permissions

Tags: windows-10, file-permissions

I'm trying to fix the permissions on a directory and its contents, but I'm getting an error.

I log in as an admin and modify the permissions for the directory, no problem. Then I click the box to apply inherited permissions to all objects inside the directory, and I get

```
An error occurred while applying security information to
<filename>

Failed to enumerate objects in the container. Access is denied.
```

I click "OK", but the error comes up for file after file. After clicking "OK"  200 times with no end in sight, I gave up.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try taking ownership of the folder and all subfolders and files first.

Comment: @SamForbis Take ownership as the admin user, then set it back to the rightful owner?

Comment: Slightly relevant: https://superuser.com/questions/1150945/is-it-possible-to-change-ntfs-permissions-on-a-big-tree-faster

Comment: You don't need to set it back. An owner's only special power is the privilege of always changing permissions on a file EVEN if they don't have permission too. Any existing permissions don't get changed.

Comment: @SamForbis Taking ownership fixed it -- please post as answer! Also, this was useful: https://appuals.com/fix-failed-enumerate-objects-container/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are trying to change permissions on a folder with subfolders/files, you will sometimes have to take ownership of that folder and its contents before you can change permissions on everything.

Change owner in the folder's Properties -> Security -> Advanced area, and make sure "Replace owner on subcontainers and objects" is checked.

Depending on your setup, you may need to revert the folder's ownership back to the previous owner after you change the permissions to ensure nothing breaks after you do this.