# Can't delete folder of unexisting fonts

Tags: windows-10

I have a folder that I want to delete that is full of fonts. It has in it only like "bakery.otf" or "Julietta.otf". Trying to delete one of those gives me an "You require permission from the computer administrator to make changes to this file". I tried deleting the folder using the Unlocker app and the "Wise Force Deleter" one, both being unable to delete the folder. I also tried looking in regedit in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Fonts but the fonts don't appear there. When trying to open one of the fonts, it says "The requested file ... is not a valid font file." Also tried deleting using cmd del command, also didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Run `chkdsk` on the disk.

Comment: You haven't been specific about where the folder is located, assuming it's the C:\Windows\Fonts folder? If it is, I wouldn't worry about the fonts. If it is not, the error you receive has been answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1523349/cannot-apply-inherited-permissions).

Answer (score 0):

G'day.
Am assuming you have Admin access but it seems you need to take Ownership of the file/folder. Also, have you right clicked and checked in Properties?
Folder may be Blocked, so untick and try again.

Comment: Trying to give myself full control permission in properties gives me the error: "An error occurred while applying security information to: ...
Failed to enumerate objects in the container. Access is denied."